# Need help with evaluating an integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Given that $f$ is continuous and positive, and

$$I=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{f(\sin (x))}{f(\sin (x)) + f(\cos(x))}\mathrm dx $$

I Know that $I=\dfrac{\pi}{4}$.

Answer (score 4):

**HINT**

If you make the change of variable $y = \pi/2 - x$, you get

\begin{align*}
I = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{f(\cos(x))}{f(\cos(x)) + f(\sin(x))}\mathrm{d}x
\end{align*}

Then add both expressions of $I$ and see what happens.